# Preimage of domain of holomorphy is also a domain of holomorphy

Tags: complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

I'm working on an exercise concerning about domain of holomorphy from Krantz's Function Theory of Several Complex Variables:

> Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}^{n}$ be a domain of holomorphy and  let $\Omega_0 \subset \mathbb{C}^{k}$ be another domain of holomorphy. Assume that $f$ : $\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{k}$ is a holomorphic mapping. Prove that preimage $f^{-1}(\Omega_0) \cap \Omega$ is a domain  of holomorphy.

This proposition gives ample examples of domain of holomorphy. I focus on the definition of domain of holomorphy, but I have no idea how to deal with $\partial(f^{-1}(\Omega_0) \cap \Omega)$. Maybe I should consider the holomorphically convex property by Cartan-Thullen Theorem. Which is the proper way? Is there any relevant reference for this problem?
Appreciate any help!

Comment: I do not have his book at home but something is missing here since I can take a constant map $f$ with value in $\Omega_0$ and then conclude that $\Omega$ is a domain of holomorphy, regardless of its shape.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I am very sorry that I did not understand your statement. If $f$ is a constant map with value in $\Omega_0$, $f^{-1}(\Omega_0) = \Omega$. According to assumptions, the conclusion holds. Is there something I missed? [the link of this problem, p164](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Function_Theory_of_Several_Complex_Varia/bL8jDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1)

Comment: Sorry, I did not read your post carefully.